# Use single pointer instead of double pointer

Tags: c, double-pointer

In the below piece of C code, I would like to access the foo_array in the main function using single pointer to simple_struct. Is it possible? I am asking this because for some reason, framework doesn't allow me to pass double pointers as function parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    float b;
} simple_struct;

void get_foo_value(simple_struct **foo_p)
{
    simple_struct foo_array[2] = {{1,2.1},
                                  {3,4.1}};

    *foo_p = foo_array;
}

int main()
{
    simple_struct *foo_p = 0;
    get_foo_value(&foo_p);
}
```

Comment: Use a reference instead. Or if have to ise a pointer, use a reference to a pointer

Comment: @DeepeshChoudhary Language is tagged `C` - which doesn't have references.

Comment: @Adrian - Reinstate Monica oops sorry

Comment: The code you already have is buggy. `foo_array` has automatic storage, meaning you can only legitimately access it before `get_foo_value` returns. Once `get_foo_value` returns, you are no longer allowed to reference `foo_array`, directly or via a pointer. What you are attempting to do is *Undefined Behaviour*. You need to use `malloc`.

Comment: ...or static storage (via the `static` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the "double pointer" argument (in your case, at least) by having the `get_foo_value` function *return* the pointer!

Also, as you have written it, your `foo_array` is ***local*** to the function and will not be valid after the return. You can address this in one of two ways:

1. Either make it a `static` variable (but then all calls will return a pointer to the *same* data).
2. Or use `malloc` to create a new array (remembering to release that memory with `free` at some point later).

Here's a version using the first suggestion:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    float b;
} simple_struct;

simple_struct* get_foo_value(void)
{
    static simple_struct foo_array[2] = {{1,2.1}, {3,4.1}};

    return foo_array;
}

int main()
{
    simple_struct *foo_p = get_foo_value();
}
```

And here's a possible solution using the `malloc` method:

```c
simple_struct* get_foo_value(void)
{
    simple_struct foo_array[2] = {{1,2.1}, {3,4.1}};
    simple_struct* answer = malloc(sizeof(foo_array));
    memcpy(answer, foo_array, sizeof(foo_array));
    return answer;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when we want to return a value, we use `return`.

```
simple_struct *get_foo_value(void) {
    simple_struct *foo = malloc(...);
    // Initialize *foo...
    return foo;
}

{
    simple_struct *foo = get_foo_value();
}
```

But may the return value is used for something else. In that situation, we can use a parameter. A parameter variable is local to its function, so changes to its value has no effect on the caller. So when we want a function to change a variable in the caller, we pass a pointer to the variable. This means that if we wanted to return a pointer using a parameter, we'd have to use a pointer to a pointer.

```
void get_foo_value(simple_struct **foo_ptr) {
    *foo_ptr = malloc(...);
    // Initialize **foo_ptr...
}

{
    simple_struct *foo;
    get_foo_value(&foo);
}
```

But you want alternatives.

You could wrap the pointer in a struct.

```
typedef struct {
   simple_struct *ptr;
} simple_struct_ptr;

void get_foo_value(simple_struct_ptr *rv) {
    simple_struct *foo = malloc(...);
    // Initialize *foo...
    rv->ptr = foo;
}

{
    simple_struct_ptr foo_ptr;
    get_foo_value(&foo_ptr);
    simple_struct *foo = foo_ptr.ptr;
}
```

You could wrap the pointer in a typedef.

```
typedef simple_struct *simple_struct_ptr;

void get_foo_value(simple_struct_ptr *rv) {
    simple_struct *foo = malloc(...);
    // Initialize *foo...
    *rv = foo;
}

{
    simple_struct *foo;
    get_foo_value(&foo);
}
```

Both of these solution would be considered bad practice. Hiding the fact that a pointer is a pointer hinders readability.